# Javascript location variable changes webpage address

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Well I was working with javascript for my project and found out something interesting. In my javascript code when I do something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Array</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var location = ["Kathmandu","Bhaktapur","Lalitpur"];
            console.log(location);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

save the file as **array.html** and when I try to run the webpage the URL changes indicating filename as 'Kathmandu,Bhaktapur,Lalitpur'. I am surprised myself with this behaviour and wanted to know why it happen. Btw I am using safari as my web-browser and haven`t tried this on any other browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`location` is an object that holds the location/url of the page, so you should avoid using it as a variable.

> **Location Object**
>
> The location object contains information about the current URL.
>
> The location object is part of the window object and is accessed
>   through the window.location property.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp